# how to change default table text wrapping in word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word

**Problem** I'm trying to create a new table style that has some space between the text right under the table.

When I select a single table and go to table properties, I can set the text wrapping to 'Around' and then select the bottom space to be 0.25 or whatever.

But when I try to define table properties in the style definition, the option for text wrapping is greyed out. Why is that and how can I change the default text wrapping of tables?